# Create a selective stylesheet using gulp

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp

I am trying to figure out a way using gulp to create a new CSS sheet based on either my SCSS partials, or my compiled CSS. The new sheet would only include specific rules that were somehow flagged.

I have two ideas on how this might work, but I cant seem to think of a way to make this happen, so I am looking for some suggestions.

Option 1) Use some comment flag in the SCSS partials that indicate which rules should be included. These styles will be included both in the full CSS sheet, and the selective one. 
-or-
Option 2) Have a config file that is basically an array of selectors and have gulp find every instance of those selectors in the compiled CSS and create a new CSS sheet with those rules.

Hopefully that makes sense, and also ins't a repeat question, I tried to search for this, but wasn't sure how to word the request.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an easy thing to do! Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Thats what I'm finding. Its for a CMS, the editor uses a separate style sheet, but it doesn't need all of the styles

Answer (score 0):

Just create different folders with different SCSS files which you then bundle into different CSS files. So for example make a folder structure like this:

```
rule1_scss -> folder with scss files for first rule 
rule2_scss -> folder with scss files for second rule...
```

In gulp then just include folder rule1_scss when making CSS file for usage with rule1 and same for rule2. Solution has lots of unnecessary files but it is a simple solution.